# way to fetch the argument inside perl script

Tags: perl, shell

I am having some trouble of getting the argument passed in in the following script

```
echo "abc"|perl <<'EOF'
#how to get "abc". it seems not $ARGV[0] nor in <STDIN>
EOF
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Redirecting stdin with both a pipe and a heredoc won't work.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194046/94637) Can you please explain exactly what you're trying to do and why?

Answer (score 1):

The precise command line you have there may be your problem, if that is what you're actually executing. What you are saying there is "put 'abc' on the standard input of the next thing in the pipeline. Now run a Perl script consisting of a single comment."

This will do nothing, because there's nothing executable in that Perl script. Try this:

```
echo "abc" | perl -e 'print <STDIN>'
```

If you have a short Perl script the `-e` option is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not using argument, it's using standard input. You can read standard input with [the I/O operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2FO-Operators). If you actually mean that you want an argument like `myscript.pl --arg` then I would recommend using [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed any argument to the Perl script.

You redirected the Perl script itself so it comes from standard input; that means that the piped output goes nowhere and cannot be seen by Perl.

Reconsider how you're invoking your script.  Maybe:

```
perl script.pl "abc"
```

where `script.pl` is a file that contains the Perl script you used as a here-document.  Or simply make that script executable (perhaps without the `.pl` suffix).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that both the pipe and the here-document redirect the STDIN.  And the here-document wins, so the perl process never sees the pipe; it gets the script on STDIN (and has read to EOF before running the script, so that will see STDIN at EOF).

Observe:

```
$ echo "abc" | perl <<'EOF'
print "[What have we here?]\n";
seek(STDIN, 0, 0);
print <STDIN>;
print "[Well, what do you know ...]\n";
EOF
[What have we here?]
print "[What have we here?]\n";
seek(STDIN, 0, 0);
print <STDIN>;
print "[Well, what do you know ...]\n";
[Well, what do you know ...]
$
```

Moral: Don't try to mix pipes and here-documents in the shell. :)